# Cannot make gnat-llvm : Ada.Strings.Text_Output" is not a predefined library unit

Tags: llvm, ada, gnat

I do a make for gnat-llvm on ubuntu. (https://github.com/AdaCore/gnat-llvm)
I have ggc-9 installed, I tried also with gcc-10.

failure just at the beginning of the build:

```
make -C llvm-interface build gnatlib-automated
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/gcalliet/sda3/gnat-llvm/llvm-interface »
mkdir -p obj obj-tools/libgnat bin gnat_src/vast
for f in `cd /home/gcalliet/sda3/gnat-llvm/llvm-interface/gnat_src; ls gen_il*.ad? xutil.ad? *-tmpl xoscons.adb        xsnamest.adb`; \
do \
  cp -p /home/gcalliet/sda3/gnat-llvm/llvm-interface/gnat_src/$f obj-tools; \
    done
cd obj-tools && gnatmake -q -j0 xoscons xsnamest && ./xsnamest && \
mv -f snames.ns ../obj/snames.ads && mv -f snames.nb ../obj/snames.adb && \
gnatmake -g -q -j0 gen_il-main.adb -I../obj -Ilibgnat && ./gen_il-main && \
mv -f nmake.adb nmake.ads seinfo.ads sinfo-nodes.ads sinfo-nodes.adb einfo-entities.ads einfo-entities.adb
../obj
gen_il-main.adb:26:06: "Ada.Strings.Text_Output" is not a predefined library unit
gen_il-main.adb:26:06: "Gen_Il.Main (body)" depends on "Gen_Il (spec)"
gen_il-main.adb:26:06: "Gen_Il (spec)" depends on "Ada.Strings.Text_Output (spec)"
gnatmake: "gen_il-main.adb" compilation error`
```

What did I missed?

Comment: `Ada.Strings.Text_Output` is in FSF GCC 11, GNAT CE 2020.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the current `master` branch of `gnat-llvm` cannot be build with the current master branch of `gcc` (`gnat`). Both are under heavy development and are apparently out-of-sync at the time of writing. You could try to build `gnat-llvm` using branch `21.2` (or some later commit between `21.2` and `master`) together with `gcc` branch `releases/gcc-11` (although I have to admit that I didn't try it myself).

Note that `gnat-llvm` branch `21.2` still depends on LLVM 10. It seems that `gnat-llvm` switched to LLVM 11 in January (see [this](https://github.com/AdaCore/gnat-llvm/commit/ebd468cee49cb55a75893f480adc59754baa79c9) commit). You could also try to use this commit along with `gcc` branch `releases/gcc-11` to build `gnat-llvm` if LLVM 10 is not available in your Linux distro.